# Subgroup of countably infinite index in a compact group

Tags: compactness, topological-groups

Suppose $G$ is a compact (Polish, if it helps) group and $H\leq G$ is of countable index. Does it follow that the index is finite? If the answer is yes, what if we only know that the index is just strictly less than $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Equivalently, can a compact Hausdorff group act transitively on a countably infinite set? (Or an infinite set of cardinality below $2^{\aleph_0}$.)

I can show it under additional assumption that $H$ has the property of Baire (in this case, index under $2^{\aleph_0}$ implies that $H$ is clopen). On the other hand, it is not that hard to find examples where $H$ does not have the property of Baire (e.g. the kernel of a discontinuous functional on an infinite-dimensional vector space over a finite field), but the examples I know are all of finite index.

Comment: Every infinite abelian group has a subgroup of infinite countable index. This applies for instance to the $p$-adic group $\mathbf{Z}_p$ (just use a nonzero $\mathbf{Q}$-linear form on $\mathbf{Q}_p$).

Comment: hi @YCor; is it straightforward to see that every infinite abelian group has a subgroup of countably infinite index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't follow that $H$ has to have finite index.

For example you can look at [This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.6837.pdf) paper Theorem 2.3

"Every infinite compact group G that is not profinite has a
subgroup of countable index and thus contains a non-measurable subgroup."

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look hard enough, it seems. :)

Comment: I think this should be attributed to Simon Thomas (+ direct application of Peter-Weyl). (By the way "infinite" is superfluous in the assumption since finite groups are profinite.)